# Gerenciamento de arquivos parecido com Google Drive

Tags: asp.net

Eu estava procurando de como criar um gerenciamento de dados parecido com **One Drive, Google Drive**, etc. E acabei de deparando com [isso](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/8872/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/File-Management/File-Manager/Visual-Elements/Visual-Elements-Overview) e não entendi muito bem como aplicar isso em uma aplicação WEB, poderiam me dar uma direção de como criar algo similar ?

Comment: confira se o link está correto, ele faz referência ao botão de ir para a pasta acima, não faz sentido com a pergunta

Comment: @Sveen corrigido